# Profiling in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, profiling, profiler

I am having a free-form project in NetBeans and using NetBeans to profile my project. I am running my project with different customer scenarios and I want to capture the profiling data for EACH and EVERY METHOD that was hit in these scenarios.

However, it seems that NetBeans will show the profiling data for the main method and some other methods that were called from the main method. Netbeans will show the profiling data for only those methods (and methods called from those) which I have explicitly selected as root methods. Even if I choose profile "entire application" it doesnt work. My application is a huge one and it will take a lot of time to go to each class and select the methods and classes.

Comment: Have you tried [random pausing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024)? Despite being crude, it finds problems in no time.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the whole packages as the profiling roots.